# Google Chrome can't run script in FB javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a sample code:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxx', // App ID from the App Dashboard
        status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
        cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          var page_id = "40796308305"; // cocacola
          if (response && response.authResponse) {
            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
            FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                $('#fbframe').css('display', 'none');
              } else {
                $('#fbframe').css('display', 'block');
              }
            });
          } else {
            alert("Login to like");
          }
    });   
}
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And html

```
<div id="fbframe">
   <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
</div>
```

When I run code, has liked page facebook.com/coca-cola, but `$('#fbframe').css('display', 'none');` not run in chrome(firefox run OK)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the jQuery library hasn't yet loaded when you first call it.

If you are going to be using jQuery, you need to make sure the document has loaded first.

Wrap you loginStatus call like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          var page_id = "40796308305"; // cocacola
          if (response && response.authResponse) {
            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
            FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                $('#fbframe').css('display', 'none');
              } else {
                $('#fbframe').css('display', 'block');
              }
            });
          } else {
            alert("Login to like");
          }
    });   
});
```